# HTML Textbox which accepts phonenumbers and has a displays in us phone number format

Tags: javascript, html

I found a lot of help in restricting a textbox to accept only numbers but I wanted to check if it is possible to display a text box in USA phone number format.

Example:

( _ _ _ ) _ _ _  - _ _ _ _

Please help.

Comment: Honestly? Your best approach is to allow the user to enter the phone number however they like, then strip away all the "filler" characters and reformat on the `onblur` event.

Forcing the user to enter according to the template is difficult, breaks normal editing and _unexpected_.  Don't surprise your users.

Comment: +1 Jeremy. If a particular format is required, it should be suggested by an on–screen tool tip or hint, not by forcing the user to modify how they choose to enter data.

Answer (score 0):

I did a google search for you and found this. I believe it is exactly what you are wanting

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/javascript-phone-format-phone-number-format.aspx

Comment: That has the same issue that almost all of those formatting functions have.  In particular, if you to to type in a phone number like "33081" and you realize that you actually meant "340 81" you have to hit backspace two a total of FOUR times to "undo" the formatting.  This drives touch-typists NUTS.

Comment: Editing that code to detect key code for backspace and determining the caret location can fix that.

Comment: @bot—and if you just let the user enter the number without forcing them to do it your way, you don't need any (often problematic) scripting and users are happy.

Comment: @Bot - I didn't say it couldn't be done.  I said that writing one that worked well was difficult and just used that as one example of how it failed basic usability.  Enter "919 999" then go back and try to change the "919" to "928" and see how the cursor jumps around.  It doesn't act like a normal control, it is *broken* and it is far, far more difficult to write one that *works* than people think.

Comment: @Bot thanks for the info.. will try to use this in "On Blur" event... to avoid issue raised by Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

The US phone numbering scheme, ignoring the country code component, is:

```
[2-9][0-9][0-9] [2-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Which can be suggested to users something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fieldLabel">Phone number:
    <td><input id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"><br>
        <span class="screenTip">Format: 999&nbsp;999&nbsp;9999</span>
</table>
```

An application only cares that the value is valid when the user submits the form (or sends the data), whatever it is in the meantime is irrelevant. It's extremely difficult to use script to implement a user friendly field that restricts input as the user keys (or pastes or drops) it in for only a few browsers. It's probably impossible for all browsers in use.

On the other hand, validating the value when submitted or the field loses focus is quite easy, as is a user friendly message to correct any errors (leaving the value alone, let the user correct it).